# SendAsync is not working from an External server (Web API2)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We are running into a situation where sendAsync post call from a server is not working. Here's my scenario

We have a Web API hosted on a server outside our internal network (DMZ) which has a simple GET implemented to it as

```
Public HttpResponseMessage Get(strind id){ (API 1)

//do some work
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient()){     

//We Invoke another web API which is hosted inside our network and do a post   //    as

HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
message.Content = new StringContent(someStr);
message.Content.Header.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

try{
var response = client.SendAsync(message).Result (API 2)

}
catch(Exception e){
//Something
 }
}
```

The post SendAsync().Results fails with the following exception

> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) and the message says as One or More errors Occurred.

The innerexception is also not telling anything good. It just InnerException.StackTrace is coming blank and the InnerException.Message is An error occurred while sending request.

In order to test the communication, we ran a GET request from the external sever for API 2 and it worked fine but the POST's are not working.

Everything works fine when both the API's (the one for get and the other one that does the post) are hosted on our internal servers.

Any Suggestions why this might not be working when executed from the external server?

Comment: Look at the inner inner exception.

Comment: @Slaks we did as i have mentioned above "he innerexception is also not telling anything good. it just InnerException.StackTrace is coming blank and the InnerException.Message is An error occurred while sending request.
"

Comment: Check the **inner** InnerException

Comment: Try changing to `var response = client.SendAsync(message).GetAwaiter().GetResult();` for a better exception message that isn't wrapped in an AggragateException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Regardless of what I'm betting on, you have to inspect those inner exceptions and find out the exact message.

Longer answer:
The fact that when you host the application in your internal network, the code works (the POST call is successful) and when moved to DMZ it fails strongly indicates the server making the call has no access to the remote endpoint.

I'd bet on the lack of network connectivity between your App Server and the `API 2`.

Comment: thanks @Bruno and sorry for the late reply. I just looked into inner exceptions and found the actual error message. It was related to the  root certificates not allowing the POST to work. Network team has to go in and install the certificate with a specific credentials they had setup, on the DMZ and then it started working. I will mark this as answer